# Xamarin.Forms xaml views, navigation and binding

Tags: binding, navigation, xamarin.forms

I am trying to setup a simple main page with a title and status bar, and dynamically change the middle content.
I'd like to keep the views in xaml as much as possible.
The issue I am having is with binding.  The MainView bindings work fine.
But the bindings to my title, status, and page views don't work.
Am I setting up the navigation correctly?

Here's my MainView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainView">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.Children>                
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                        Text="Show Menu" 
                        Command="{Binding ShowMenuCommand}" 
                        BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
                <local:TitleBarView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                        Text="Show Options" 
                        Command="{Binding ShowOptionsCommand}" 
                        BackgroundColor="Lime"/>
                <ContentView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                             x:Name="MainContent" />                
                <local:StatusBarView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
            </Grid.Children>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

My TitleBarView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.TitleBarView">
    <ContentView.Content> 
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Label Text="TitleInfo1: " TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding TitleInfo1}" TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="TitleInfo2: " TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding TitleInfo2}" TextColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My StatusBarView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.StatusBarView">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="Green">
            <Label Text="StatusInfo1: " TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding StatusInfo1}" TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="StatusInfo2: " TextColor="White"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding StatusInfo2}" TextColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My Page1View.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Page1View">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="{Binding Page1Info}"/>
            <Button Text="Go To Page 2" Command="{Binding GoToPage2Command}"/>
        </StackLayout >
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

My Page2View.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Page2View">  
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Text="{Binding Page2Info}"/>
            <Button Text="Go To Page 1" Command="{Binding GoToPage1Command}"/>
            <Button Text="Go To Page 3" Command="{Binding GoToPage3Command}"/>
        </StackLayout >
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

etc...

My base view model class that implements notification

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My MainViewModel.cs

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private const string TAG = "MainViewModel";

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "MainViewModel()");
    }

    #region ShowMenuCommand
    private Command _showMenuCommand;
    public ICommand ShowMenuCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_showMenuCommand == null)
                _showMenuCommand = new Command(param => this.showMenuClick());
            return _showMenuCommand;
        }
    }

    public void showMenuClick()
    {
        Logger.ui(TAG, "showMenuClick()");
        //ToDo: show main menu
    }
    #endregion

    #region ShowOptionsCommand
    private Command _showOptionsCommand;
    public ICommand ShowOptionsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_showOptionsCommand == null)
                _showOptionsCommand = new Command(param => this.showOptionsClicked());
            return _showOptionsCommand;
        }
    }

    public void showOptionsClicked()
    {
        Logger.ui(TAG, "showOptionsClicked()");
        //ToDo: show options menu
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My TitleBarViewModel.cs

```
class TitleBarViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private const string TAG = "TitleBarViewModel";

    public TitleBarViewModel()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "TitleBarViewModel()");
    }

    #region TitleInfo1
    private string _titleInfo1 = "This is title info 1";
    public string TitleInfo1
    {
        get { return _titleInfo1; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_titleInfo1))
            {
                _titleInfo1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TitleInfo1");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region TitleInfo2
    private int _titleInfo2 = 14;
    public int TitleInfo2
    {
        get { return _titleInfo2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _titleInfo2)
            {
                _titleInfo2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TitleInfo2");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My StatusBarViewModel.cs

```
class StatusBarViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private const string TAG = "StatusBarViewModel";

    public StatusBarViewModel()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "StatusBarViewModel()");
    }

    #region StatusInfo1
    private string _statusInfo1 = "This is Status Info 1";
    public string StatusInfo1
    {
        get { return _statusInfo1; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_statusInfo1))
            {
                _statusInfo1 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusInfo1");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region StatusInfo2
    private string _statusInfo2 = "This is Status Info 2";
    public string StatusInfo2
    {
        get { return _statusInfo2; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_statusInfo2))
            {
                _statusInfo2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("StatusInfo2");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My Page1ViewModel.cs

```
class Page1ViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private const string TAG = "Page1ViewModel";

    public Page1ViewModel()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "Page1ViewModel()");
    }

    #region Page1Info
    private string _page1Info = "This is Page 1 Info";
    public string Page1Info
    {
        get { return _page1Info; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_page1Info))
            {
                _page1Info = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Page1Info");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Go To Page 2
    private Command _goToPage2Command;
    public ICommand GoToPage2Command
    {
        get
        {
            if (_goToPage2Command == null)
                _goToPage2Command = new Command(param => this.goToPage2Clicked());
            return _goToPage2Command;
        }
    }

    public void goToPage2Clicked()
    {
        Logger.ui(TAG, "goToPage2Clicked()");
        NavigationController.setContentPage(typeof(Page2View));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

etc ...

My NavigationController.cs

```
public class NavigationController
{
    private const string TAG = "NavigationController";

    static MainView mainView;
    static MainViewModel mainViewModel;

    static TitleBarView titleBarView;
    static TitleBarViewModel titleBarViewModel;

    static StatusBarView statusBarView;
    static StatusBarViewModel statusBarViewModel;

    static List<ContentView> viewList = new List<ContentView>();
    static ContentView currentView;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "Initialize()");

        mainView = new MainView();
        mainViewModel = new MainViewModel();
        mainView.BindingContext = mainViewModel;

        titleBarView = new TitleBarView();
        titleBarViewModel = new TitleBarViewModel();
        titleBarView.BindingContext = titleBarViewModel;

        statusBarView = new StatusBarView();
        statusBarViewModel = new StatusBarViewModel();
        statusBarView.BindingContext = statusBarViewModel;

        Page1View view1 = new Page1View();
        Page1ViewModel viewModel1 = new Page1ViewModel();
        view1.BindingContext = viewModel1;
        viewList.Add(view1);

        Page2View view2 = new Page2View();
        Page2ViewModel viewModel2 = new Page2ViewModel();
        view2.BindingContext = viewModel2;
        viewList.Add(view2);

        Page3View view3 = new Page3View();
        Page3ViewModel viewModel3 = new Page3ViewModel();
        view3.BindingContext = viewModel3;
        viewList.Add(view3);

        mainView.setMainContent(view1);
        currentView = view1;
    }

    public static Page getMainPage()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "getMainPage()");
        return mainView;
    }

    public static void setContentPage(Type type)
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "setContentPage(" + type.ToString() + ")");
        foreach (ContentView cv in viewList)
        {
            if (cv.GetType() == type)
            {
                if (cv != currentView)
                {
                    mainView.setMainContent(cv);
                    currentView = cv;
                    Logger.mt(TAG, "setContentPage() FOUND");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        Logger.mt(TAG, "setContentPage() NOT FOUND");
    }
}
```

And to set the view, I edited the MainView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainView : ContentPage
{
    private const string TAG = "MainView";

    public MainView()
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "MainView()");
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool setMainContent(ContentView view)
    {
        Logger.mt(TAG, "setMainContent()");
        MainContent.Content = view.Content;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Xamarin.Forms provides something that you are looking for. It's called templates. Check it out: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/templates/control-templates/introduction/